# How to make a component use v-for have dynamic slots

Tags: vue.js, dynamic, components, v-for

I have a child component that uses v-for. I want to be able to have the parent pass down a slot, or something similar of how it wants each item in the v-for display. However, the problem is that the parent does not have access to each individual item in the v-for as it's rendered.

Some things i've tried is passing a slot with specific keys. e.g.

```
<child-comp :items="items">
    <div v-text="item.text" slot="body"/>
</child-comp>
```

Basic code may look like this for what i'm trying (though it doesn't work)

Parent component would look something like

```
<template>
   <child-comp :items="items>
     <div v-text="item.text"
    </child-comp>
</template>
items = [{ text: 'hello'}]
```

Child would look something like this

```
<template>
  <div>
     <span v-for="item in items">
       <slot></slot>
     </span>
  </div>
</template>
```

Note this has to be dynamic because one item might do v-text, another may do something like add more html such as an image, and another may do something completely different.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you're looking for scoped slots.

https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-slots.html#Scoped-Slots

Note that the preferred syntax for using scoped slots changed in Vue 2.6.0 so the exact way you write this will depend on which version you're using.

Your child would pass the `item` to the slot, like this:

```html
<template>
  <div>
    <span v-for="item in items">
      <slot :item="item"></slot>
    </span>
  </div>
</template>
```

The parent would look like this for Vue 2.6.0+:

```html
<template>
  <child-comp :items="items">
    <template v-slot:default="slotProps">
      <!-- The parent can put whatever it needs here -->
      {{ slotProps.item }}
    </template>
  </template>
  </child-comp>
</template>
```

Any props passed to the slot by the child will be included in the `slotProps`. There's no need to call it `slotProps` and in practice it is usually destructured (see the docs for more details).

For Vue 2.5 you'd use `slot-scope` instead:

```html
<template>
  <child-comp :items="items">
    <template slot-scope="slotProps">
      <!-- The parent can put whatever it needs here -->
      {{ slotProps.item }}
    </template>
  </template>
  </child-comp>
</template>
```

Prior to Vue 2.5.0 `slot-scope` was called `scope`.